# file selector from disk option in grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, groovy

I want to create a simple gsp page which will have an input box with a 'load from disk' button onclick of which a file selector dialog opens up allowing me to select a file and displaying the whole path into the text box after selection.
I eventually plan to read this file contents into database.

What input type is used for file selector option?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
<input type="file" id="payload" name="payload"/>
```

Try google for 'grails file upload' and you will find multiple examples